# How can I prevent an added "columns" style property from cutting text in Safari 10?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

In Safari 10.0, I noticed a bug: after the page loads, if I add `style="columns: 2"` to an HTML element with text, a line of text will sometimes be cut into two pieces.

[image: Safari column bug]

You can also see the problem with this JSFiddle in Safari 10.0 if you click "Run" and play with the window size: https://jsfiddle.net/az1so91v/2/

My web app requires setting such columns after the page renders. How can I prevent the text from being cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a better answer, but I'll share what I've been doing to get around the problem.

I suspected that forcing Safari to re-render the text might cause the column heights to be recalculated, so I tried changing the padding by an unnoticeable amount after the columns were set, and it worked. What I'm doing now is setting `padding-left: 0.00001px` on `p` elements as soon as the columns are set, and then using `window.setTimeout` to set back `padding-left: 0`.

This JSFiddle demonstrates my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/q7washrL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your container

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. (It does technically work if I apply it to `p` elements, but then it avoids breaking paragraphs between the columns, and I *want* to break the paragraphs between the columns, like a book.)